# Drag_and_drop_helper.js isnt working (python,Selenium)

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get Drag_And_drop_help_js to work on my selenium script but I haven't had any luck

I have tried using different combinations of js code to get this working still hasn't worked

```
    # coding = utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
X = 1
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver')
jquery_url = "/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"

time.sleep(3)
# load jQuery helper

with open("/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/jquery_load_helper.js") as f:
    load_jquery_js = f.read()

# load drag and drop helper
with open("/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/drag_and_drop_helper.js") as f:
    drag_and_drop_js = f.read()

# load jQuery
browser.execute_async_script(load_jquery_js, jquery_url)

time.sleep(3)
# perform drag&drop

browser.execute_script(drag_and_drop_js + "$('img._1SHoi3TpKUXlEGqlgZ2vd2._3rlZNaFpVhbk2o4Z0FDo6s._1xHwr15CE9cPMNGOn0zEj').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: 'div._31Rs25Go5jOLli-OJEzoMA._30rwedNTbMR7KpB_wNp3RD'});")
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: jQuery is not defined
```

I want to move one image to another location. using drag and drop
Help will be much appreciated

Comment: Could you tell us what's happening? What exactly have you tried, and what was the output?

Comment: I've tried Two ways but kept iterating them and trying to get them working one other way was this: https://textuploader.com/153uj

Comment: What is the error? What is the result? What is occurring when you try what you're trying? "It doesn't work" makes it very time consuming for us to help you & most will likely just not bother. If you gave us examples of the errors you're seeing, we could isolate the issue better than having to basically recreate your code & get the errors ourselves.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Kept on getting this so I move on to the current version but still haven't gotten it to work. any suggestions?

Comment: Yes I completely understand sorry for the in convince really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error that `JQuery is not defined` because DragAndDropHelper is dependent on JQuery, but you're loading it before loading JQuery.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
X = 1
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver')
jquery_url = "/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"

time.sleep(3)

# load jQuery helper
with open("/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/jquery_load_helper.js") as f:
    load_jquery_js = f.read()   

# load jQuery BEFORE libraries
browser.execute_async_script(load_jquery_js, jquery_url) 

# load drag and drop helper
with open("/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/drag_and_drop_helper.js") as f:
    drag_and_drop_js = f.read()

time.sleep(3)
# perform drag&drop

browser.execute_script(drag_and_drop_js + "$('img._1SHoi3TpKUXlEGqlgZ2vd2._3rlZNaFpVhbk2o4Z0FDo6s._1xHwr15CE9cPMNGOn0zEj').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: 'div._31Rs25Go5jOLli-OJEzoMA._30rwedNTbMR7KpB_wNp3RD'});")
```

Comment: This still doesn't work because async_script calling load_jquery_js before its declared

Comment: I don't get that error when I run that version of the script I only get it when I'm using this version https://textuploader.com/153uj

Comment: I'll show you the one I get when I run the current version just need a second

Comment: Try that edit. I'm not really sure what the necessity is of `jquery_load_helper` is. What do you mean when you say you don't get "that error". What error is "that error"?

Comment: I get this error even when I run your version selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds

Comment: If i remove load_jquery_js i get this error: https://textuploader.com/153uh

Comment: The first error you commented is because the page is not loading in time, but the code here is working. You'll have to investigate that. The second error is because when you deleted something you left a `}` somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure. Your original question is resolved, though. From here you're going to have to keep going down the list & investigate each error individually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191488/discussion-between-ali-al-jabur-and-codespent).

Comment: I've changed it to this: https://textuploader.com/15ism and now I get this error any help :https://textuploader.com/15ish

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way to load those:

```
for script in ['/path/to/jquery.js', '/path/to/drag_and_drop_helper.js']:
  with open(script, errors='ignore') as f:
    driver.execute_script(f.read())

# this last line I'm not sure if it will work as expected though
browser.execute_script("$('img._1SHoi3TpKUXlEGqlgZ2vd2._3rlZNaFpVhbk2o4Z0FDo6s._1xHwr15CE9cPMNGOn0zEj').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: 'div._31Rs25Go5jOLli-OJEzoMA._30rwedNTbMR7KpB_wNp3RD'});")
```

Comment: still getting this error:selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: jQuery is not defined

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: yes I did and it doesn't give me an error but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Download a fresh version of jQuery and put it in the folder with your script, then remove the path info.

Comment: I've changed it to this: https://textuploader.com/15ism and now I get this error any help :https://textuploader.com/15ish

Comment: We cannot just keep going through each error and debug this for you.. your question has been answered. Ask a new question and accept your answer.